# Please help to interpret a Matlab function that I am trying to rewrite in Python

Tags: python, matlab, orbital-mechanics

So I've recently been learning Python, I thought I would challenge myself by trying to recreate some Matlab code I used during my masters degree. I'm not doing it for any reason other than to see if I could, and as I don't have Matlab anymore, it would also be quite nice to be able to play with the code. The program is used to plot an orbit around the Moon, as such, it uses orbital mechanics and specific modules like SpiceyPy.

I've been able to convert most of the code so far by myself, but I'm stuck with one function, in particular. The problem is I don't fully understand what the code is doing so I can't recreate it.

This is the link to the function: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/64408/versions/1/previews/LHPOP/prop/accelpntmasses.m/index.html

Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the intent of the function is to calculate the 3rd body accelerations or perturbations from "other planets" (meaning everything but the Earth). The other bodies are being treated as point masses. The loop is iterating through each of the point masses and extracting their position and "mu" term (the GM variable) by calling into one of the JPL SPICE file functions. It accumulates the total acceleration from all the masses and returns it.

For more on the JPL SPICE file functions see [JPL SPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense as to what the loop is doing. Do you have any idea how I should interpret each of the eval functions?